# How To Export GCP Security Command Center Findings To BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, securitycenter, cloud-security

Similar to this: [How to export GCP's Security Center Assets to a Cloud Storage via cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331287/how-to-export-gcps-security-center-assets-to-a-cloud-storage-via-cloud-function)

I need to export the Findings as seen in the Security Command Center to BigQuery so we can easily filter the data we need and generate custom reports.

Using this documentation as an example (https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-api-list-findings#python), I wrote the following:

```
from google.cloud import securitycenter
from google.cloud import bigquery

JSONPath = "Path to JSON File For Service Account"
client = securitycenter.SecurityCenterClient().from_service_account_json(JSONPath)
BQclient = bigquery.Client().from_service_account_json(JSONPath)
table_id = "project.security_center.assets"
org_name = "organizations/1234567891011"
all_sources = "{org_name}/sources/-".format(org_name=org_name)
finding_result_iterator = client.list_findings(request={"parent": all_sources})
for i, finding_result in enumerate(finding_result_iterator):
    errors = BQclient.insert_rows_json(table_id, finding_result)
    if errors == []:
        print("New rows have been added.")
    else:
        print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))
```

However, that then gave me the error:

"json_rows argument should be a sequence of dicts".

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What does the `finding_result` looks like? Is it a list of dictionaries something that looks like this? `[ {"name" : "John", "age" : "20"}, {"name" : "Mike", "age": "21"}, ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort this by writing:

```
for i, finding_result in enumerate(finding_result_iterator):
rows_to_insert = [
    {u"category": finding_result.finding.category, u"name": finding_result.finding.name, u"project": finding_result.resource.project_display_name, u"external_uri": finding_result.finding.external_uri},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this existed back then in Q2 of 2021, but now there is documentation telling how to do this:
https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-analyze-findings-in-big-query

You can create exports of SCC findings to bigquery using this command:

```
gcloud scc bqexports create BIG_QUERY_EXPORT \
  --dataset=DATASET_NAME \
  --folder=FOLDER_ID | --organization=ORGANIZATION_ID | --project=PROJECT_ID \
  [--description=DESCRIPTION] \
  [--filter=FILTER]
```

Filter will allow to filter out unwanted findings (they will be in SCC, but won't be copied to the BigQuery).
It's useful if you want to export findings from one project or selected categories only. (Use `-category:CATEGORY` to exclude categories, works the same on different parameters as well).